# C# ambiguous extension methods

Tags: c#, extension-methods

LinqKit has an extension method `ForEach` for `IEnumerable` which clashes with `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`.

```
Error   4   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'LinqKit.Extensions.ForEach<Domain>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Domain>, System.Action<Domain>)' 
and 
'System.Linq.EnumerableExtensionMethods.ForEach<Domain>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Domain>, System.Action<Domain>)'
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: On a side note - Eric Lippert has some great points about why a `ForEach` extension method might not be the best idea... It's worth reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: Speaking of which, what library did `System.Linq.EnumerableExtensionMethods` come from?

Comment: @ReedCopsey Lippert's reasoning is bogus and reflects how functional programming was tacked onto C#, poorly (e.g., `select` instead of `map`, `aggregate` instead of `foldl`, no `foldr` at all ...). Scala, by contrast, has a `foreach` method even though it has a `for` statement that iterates over collections ... in fact, the `for` loop expands to calls to `foreach` (among other things). Scala allows an imperative coding style, but in various ways encourages programmers to move toward a functional style as they become more experienced.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Enumerable`, in the framework, does not declare an extension for `ForEach()`.  Both of these are from external references.

You should consider only using one of them - either the reference that's adding `EnumerableExtensionMethods` or the `LinqKit`.

(This, btw, is one reason that using the same namespace as the framework causes problems - in this case, the author of `EnumerableExtensionMethods` placed it in `System.Linq`, which is going to cause an issue any time you're using Linq and you have a namespace clash.)

If you truly need to use this method, then you'll have to call it directly instead of using the extension method, ie:

```
LinqKit.Extensions.ForEach(collection, action);
```

Or:

```
System.Linq.EnumerableExtensionMethods.ForEach(collection, action);
```

That being said, I would personally just use a foreach loop to process the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to fully-qualify the method that you're calling, as in the error message.

So, instead of using

```
ForEach<Domain>( ... );
```

use

```
LinqKit.Extensions.ForEach<Domain>( ... );
```

Comment: If the method is generic and you are using anonymous types then there is no "simply fully-qualify".